# how does bash do `ssh` autocompletion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, compgen

I've got the "bash-completion" package installed.

`ssh` completion on the command line (in `bash`) is working: `ssh TAB-TAB` will complete past used hosts and `ssh -TAB-TAB` will complete available `ssh` options.

However when I search for currently defined completions:

```
$ complete | grep ssh
complete -F _known_hosts ssh-installkeys
complete -F _service /etc/init.d/ssh
```

... I find that there's no completion registered for `ssh` ?!

```
complete -p ssh
bash: complete: ssh: no completion specification
```

When I check the `ssh` completions script under `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh` then I see that indeed it *does* register `ssh` completions:

```
$ grep complete /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh | grep ssh | grep -v '^#'
shopt -u hostcomplete && complete -F _ssh ssh slogin autossh sidedoor
```

So why doesn't the ssh completion show up in `complete | grep ssh`? How *does* bash complete the `ssh` options?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no completion defined for a command (or a function or whatever) then the "default" completer kicks in.

That default completer can be seen here:

```
$ complete -p -D
complete -F _completion_loader -D
```

When the `bash-completion` package is installed, then that will source `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` via `/etc/bash.bashrc` and that will assign the `_completion_loader` function.

`_completion_loader` will **dynamically** load specific completers upon completion request for commands the shell's completer doesn't know about yet (see [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/a234784b39e657be671f292c384395ed2fd64a75/bash_completion#L2151)).

In the case of `ssh`, the terminals where I was doing the poking around had not yet loaded the `ssh` completer and so I was not seeing it with `complete | grep ssh` or `complete -p ssh`. It's only at the moment when you press TAB-TAB for the *first time* that the completer for `ssh` gets loaded.